# ¿Por que me salen estos errores al realizar mi conexión a la base de datos con PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

Hoy empecé un nuevo proyecto y quise empezar haciendo lo mejor posible la conexión a la base de datos, estoy utilizando mysqli orientado a objetos.

Hice la conexión todo normal, no hubo problema, pero quise poner el nombre de la base de datos mal a propósito para ver que error arrojaba, y por supuesto arrojo el error de la conexión a la base de datos, pero además de ello, me arroja 3 errores más, a continuación adjunto imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces quisiera saber el por qué me arroja 3 errores más. A continuación adjunto el código fuente:

```
<?php

// Variables globales para la conexion
const DB_HOST = "IP";
const DB_USERNAME = "nombreuser";
const DB_PASSWORD = "3(2S338pQ-";
const DB_NAME = "nombredb";
const DB_ENCODE = "utf8";

// Conexión a la base de datos
$conexionMoodle = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$conexionMoodle->set_charset(DB_ENCODE);

// Por si ocurre un error
if ($conexionMoodle->connect_errno) {
    die("Fallo la conexion a MySQL: (" . $conexionMoodle->mysqli_connect_errno() . ") " . $conexionMoodle->mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    die("conectado");
}
```

Cabe resaltar que a propósito coloque mal las constantes.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Coloca el código de conexión en una estructura `try { ... } catch() { ... }` para evitar que se muestre cualquier error. [Manejo de excepciones](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: Hola Triby, ¿podrías colocar un ejemplo utilizando Try Catch con el codigo que adjunte?

Comment: Revisa los dos primeros comentarios en https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php no es tan complicado.

Comment: El error es claro: acceso denegado. Debes verificar que estás apuntando correctamente a la BD y que las credenciales son correctas. Los otros errores son consecuencia de ese primer fallo. Generalmente en el `host` se pone `localhost` o `127.0.0.1`, no la IP del equipo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunca muestres los errores de conexion manualmente amigo ya que esto puede resultar en fuga de seguridad.

Utiliza este codigo de abajo para tus conexiones a tu base de datos:

```
<?php
//Store log in info into variables
$servername = 'localhost';
$serveruser = 'user';
$serverpassword = 'password';
$serverdatabase = 'basededatos';
// Create connection
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $serveruser, $serverpassword, $serverdatabase);
```

Comment: Por cierto los errores que te salen es por que los parametros para conectar a la base de datos estan incorrectos. Entra a PHP my admin y verifica que tengas exista la base de datos, el usuario, y que el password sea el correcto.

Comment: Gracias por responder.

Amigo, yo puse los parámetros incorrectos a propósito, por eso sale el primer error, luego hay 3 errores más.

En cuanto al código que adjuntaste, la conexión es con procedimientos, yo estoy usando la conexión orientada a objetos.

Gracias.

Comment: @JesúsOrozco okey te lo he puesto el codigo en OOP la diferencia es minima. Aun asi no olvides no mostrar los errores manualmente para no tener fuga de seguridad.